# Determining source sObject of "Custom Relationship Limit Exceeded" managed package install message

Tags: managed-package, limits

I recently had an install of our managed package fail with the message:

> **Custom Relationship Limit Exceeded**
>   Cannot create new relationship. Each object can have no more than 25 custom relationships, including Master-Detail and Lookup relationships.

I understand the root cause of this message. By default each object is limited to 25 relationship fields and if I put the business case to Salesforce support this "soft" limit can be increased. See [Custom Fields Allowed Per Object](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_custom_fields.htm&language=en_US).

My issue is that it isn't immediately apparent which sObject I should be asking to have the limit increased on.

**Is there an easy way to figure out which sObject* is causing this error?**
* Or possibly which multiple sObjects are causing the error.

Failing that, are there any native or third party tools I can use to *quickly* check the current limit status of the client Org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise a case with Salesforce they can obtain more detailed error messages of app install problems which should then tell you which object needs to have its limit increased. I recently had an issue with a package where the message told me nothing useful, once I got hold of the actual error from Salesforce it was a trivial fix.

Comment: +1 as this is definitely a viable solution for determining the cause. It does have the downside of waiting for support to get back to you. I'll leave this open for a bit to see if there are any alternative solutions.

Comment: Yeah the wait isn't good. This method does work better if you hit up Reid though ;)